# Login another associated account while logged in Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm just wondering if it's possible to login a different account while currently logged in.

The scenario is a User can have multiple accounts and while logged in, there is a tab of lists of all of his accounts. Now if an account is clicked, modal pops up with a login form in it and the session now should be the account that is clicked.

I have tried Session::flush() and Auth::logout but these can't accomplish what i want since this functions redirects the page to login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
// $id => login to user id
$user = User::where('id',$id);
//login as user.
Auth::login($user);
```

have a look at the below one might be helpful for you

https://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/temporary-user-switching